# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError ngIf value changed

Tags: angular

In my code i am getting the ngIf value changed error and not sure what is the correct way to go about it. 
Here is my HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="currentVlaue">
            <div class="section-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="currentValue.name"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control" required />
                </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

In my component i have:

```
public currentValue: ValueModel;
@Input() public values: ValuesModel[];

constructor(){}  

ngOnInit(){}  

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
let indexOfValues = "someValue";
        if (changes[indexOfValues ] &&
            changes[indexOfValues ].indexOfValues  &&
            changes[indexOfValues ].previousValue !== changes[indexOfValues ].currentValue) {
            if (this.values && this.values.length > 0) {
                this.indexOfValues  = this.actions[0];
            }
        }
}
```

I also have addValue, editValue, deleteValue, and saveValue methods.
Any light to have i can resolve this error?

Comment: First of all, why you need *ngIf with two way data binding. you can maintain a boolean flag and update status right?

Comment: @bluePearl Have you tried enableProdMode() in your main.ts before bootstrapping your Application ?

Comment: @bluePearl Have you try `ChangeDetectorRef`?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya when i remove the *ngIf then i get the error name of undefined for currentValue.name

Answer (score 1):

You need to create model currentValue with property default values (empty). Also please remove ngIf code.

```
public currentValue: ValueModel = {
   name: ''
};
@Input() public values: ValuesModel[];

constructor(){}  

ngOnInit(){}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ywghz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score -1):

**Reason :** `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` will come if once the change detection is fired and scheduled for updating view and in between the value is got changed.

**Solution 1:** This error will come when we are running our application in `development` mode, not in `production` mode. In the `main.ts` where we can `enableProdMode()` before `bootstrapping` your main module.

```
// will enableProdMode condition
enableProdMode();


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Solution 2**: manually call change detection in `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I will try the ngAfterViewInit. But why was this answer voted down without a comment.

Comment: Both suggestions didnt work. Do you think that since this component is a child component that this error could be coming from the parent component?

Comment: Can you please add the slackblitz code . This will help for debugging.